# Batch file variable output

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch scrip that send me a mail using a program call mailsend.

It checks a directory and count the files and than email me the count out of 10.

" I have checked the directory, there are "8" files. Please check remaining "2".

I cannot get it to display on one line. The text is read from one txt file and the count from another, than added together. I than use type a.txt + b.txt.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add your script?

Comment: the solution depends on your already existing code (or it might be the re-invention of the wheel). Please poste your relevant code (the part that generates the text) and some info about the textfiles (are they one-liners?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on your code, but something very simple might be:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p iTotal=<"Path-to-directory\a.txt"
SET /p iRemaining=<"Path-to-directory\b.txt"

@ECHO.There are "%iTotal%" files. Please check remaining "%iRemaining%".
```

Please have a try :)

Comment: Thanks!! is it possible to give me the difference in percentage?